# Oozie cannot detect Spark workflow-app tag in XML

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I'm trying to schedule an Oozie job that runs daily. From the shell, I'm using this command–

```
oozie job -oozie $OOZIE_URL -run -verbose \
    -config $PWD/this_file_is_a_formality.properties \
    -Doozie.coord.application.path="hdfs:///path/to/file/aggregates_workflow.xml" \
    -Dstart="$START" \
    -Dend="$END"
```

(Assume all the environment variables are correctly set.)

I'm getting this error:

`Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'workflow-app'.`

I believe Oozie is parsing my workflow XML file, but it's not correctly recognizing the valid XML in the file.

The `aggregates_workflow.xml` file:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name='PREAGGREGATED'>
<global>
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <configuration>
        <property>
        ...
        </property>
    </configuration>
</global>
<start to="spark-node"/>
<action name="spark-node">
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>yarnRM</job-tracker>
        <name-node>PREAGGREGATED</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property> ...
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <master>yarn-client</master>
        <mode>client</mode>
        <name>${appName}</name>
        <class>${className}</class>
        <jar>${jarPath}</jar>
        <spark-opts>...0</spark-opts>
    </spark>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

I'd appreciate a diagnosis–any idea why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple mistake–

```
oozie job -oozie $OOZIE_URL -run -verbose \
-config $PWD/this_file_is_a_formality.properties \
-Doozie.coord.application.path="hdfs:///path/to/file/aggregates_coordinator.xml" \
-Dstart="$START" \
-Dend="$END"
```

is the proper start command–the third line was previously pointing to the workflow.